# I tried to send text component to end of screen but it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have 2 text elements in a text element. I tried to send second text element to the end but I couldn't do that how can I do it ?

```js
<Text style={[styles.text2, item.Ccolor == 'MAVI' ? {color:'rgba(14, 110, 172, 1)'}: {color:'#f7b731'},{position:'relative'}]}
                    animation={isActive ? 'bounceIn' : undefined}>
    <Text style={{textAlign:'left'}}> {item.Beyanname} </Text>
    <Text style={{position:'absolute',right:0}}> {item.Gumruk} </Text> 
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the React Native documentation, the `Text` component does not have a `position` prop.

[Text Style Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props)

Try using a `View` instead, but do note, you cannot use a `View` within a `Text`.

```js
<View style={{position:'absolute',right:0}}>
   <Text>{item.Gumruk}</Text>
</View>
```